# Android PowerProfile/BATTERY_STATS stopped working in Kitkat

Tags: android, battery, android-4.4-kitkat

I am using private API for [PowerProfile](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/os/PowerProfile.java) and since Android 4.4 (Kitkat), it stoped working. I didn´t find any reason why it should (in Android documentation).

It returns only zero values. Do you have any idea why this could stop working?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for this here: 
[Enable Battery Stats Permission on Kit Kat (Android 4.4)](http://www.rootuninstaller.com/2013/12/enable-battery-stats-permission-on-kit.html?m=1annoying)

Enable BATTERY_STATS Permission On KitKat - Xposed Module
This Xposed mod will enable any Battery Monitor application which consumes Android battery statistics to work when running KitKat (or later). The app developer may chose to integrate this function directly into their app, in which case this standalone module is not needed.
How do I install this? HELP!

This mod requires that your device is rooted, that the Xposed framework is installed, and that this module is enabled via the Xposed installer app. After a phone reboot, your battery monitoring apps should start to work as they did before KitKat rolled around.
You must have ROOT on your phone. If you do not, this is not for you.

Install this package
Download and install the Xposed installer if you do not yet have it: http://goo.gl/CKTWXZ
Install the “Framework" in the "Xposed Installer" and activate "Enable BatteryStats Permission" in "Modules".
Reboot
Run your battery monitor of choice.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for this here: [EnableBatteryStatsX on Lollipop and KitKat](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xposed-module-enablebatterystatsx-t3064688/)

Comment: Posting ONLY links for an answer is not good, you should explain your findings